# Why does RSpec/Capybara throw an error with hyphenated values provided with public_send?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have a shared example I am using to test the same thing on several controllers. I pass the controller the model and a list of fields to check to make sure they are on the page, but when the value is a hyphenated string it throws an error, even when the value is on the page. The strange thing is, though, that it drops the hyphen in the check. So, if the last name field in the user table has "Johnson-Smith" This is what I get back...

```
expected to find text matching "Johnson Smith" in...
```

And looking down in the page text it renders I can clearly see "Johnson-Smith". I don't understand why Rspec/Capybara aren't checking for the correct value. Here is the shared example code..

```
RSpec.shared_examples 'renders proper fields' do |klass, fields|
  it 'should render the expected text' do
    model_object = klass.order(:created_at).last
    fields&.each do |field|
      expect(page).to have_text(model_object.public_send(field))
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT** I tested the results for every public_send(field) that is evaluated and it turns out that public_send is returning the field from the database as expected. So the issue is, for some reason, Capybara is evaluating it without the hyphen, even though it passed the text with the hyphen.

Comment: The only way to get the error starting with "text matching ..." is if the value passed to Capybaras `have_text` matcher is a Regexp.  So either `model_object.pubvlic_send(field))` is returning a Regexp - or you're not actually calling Capybaras `have_text` matcher - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/queries/text_query.rb#L41

Comment: I can't reproduce this. https://gist.github.com/maxcal/5a72541b2ea67db25e7d63d7cacf3f4e

Comment: Even if I use `expect(page).to have_text /Hello-World/` the spec which gives the same message it passes. I think @ThomasWalpole may be onto something with it not being capybaras have_text matcher.

Comment: I will have to look and see if there is something else installed that uses a method with that name, but I don't think there is